# performing operation on usb device using java

Tags: java, usb, fingerprint

is it possible to get a usb device driver's available operations and call them using a java applet ? let's say i wanna read a fingerprint from my FP reader on Windows, despite of the possibility of using the java SDKs around the web, can i control  the device myself using java ? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes possible you can do this by using c/c++ and then import it using ***native***

keyword in java. Just googling you can find help for this.

Comment: But how can i get operations list from C++ ?